# How to import scss files in a Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, sprockets

I'm working with SCSS files in a Ruby on Rails 5.0 web app.
I have folders with project's assets. Main scss file contain all files, like this:

```
//application.scss

@import "variables"
@import "mixins"

@import "pages/home"
```

But files (home.scss, for example) don't see declared variables and mixins. 
I tried to find a solution and saw questions similar to this, but they did not work for me.

Sass-rails official doc [say that](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#important-note)

Answer (score 0):

I have error becouse rails precompile each file. Just change config assets precompile to config.assets.precompile += ['*.js']